# yii2: what is maximum value of Pagination-Per-Page into RESTful Web Service API

Tags: api, pagination, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I tried to send the parameter per-page:100 but it seems like that the returned result is maximum number of  items is 50 , how to change it

i used the following code for serilizer

```
public $serializer = [ 'class' => 'yii\rest\Serializer','collectionEnvelope' => 'items'];
```

is there a way to change the maximum value from 50 , it works for all the values less that 50 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on DataProvider configuration. You can change it by passing this in DataProvider:

```
// ...
'pagination' => [
    'defaultPageSize' => 20,
    'pageSizeLimit' => [1, 50]
],
```